# Angular AOT 2.3.1 - Compile error with route children

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli, angular2-aot

Raised and issue on angular-cli git 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3701 but was told to post it here.

My angular `2.0.0` project was working fine until the recent upgrade to angular `2.3.1`.

The following errors occurs when `children` is added to the route.

`ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'label', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol ActionTypes in C:/Workspace/xxx/src/app/game-vendor.action.ts, resolving symbol gameVendorRoutes in C:/Workspace/xxx/src/app/game-vendor/game-vendor.routing.ts, resolving symbol gameVendorRouting in C:/Workspace/
xxx/src/app/game-vendor/game-vendor.routing.ts, resolving symbol gameVendorRouting in C:/Workspace/xxx/src/app/game-vendor/game-vendor.routing.ts, resolving symbol GameVendorModule in C:/Workspace/xxx/src/app/game-vendor/game-vendor.module.ts, resolving symbol GameVendorModule in C:/Workspace/xxx/src/app/game-vendor/game-vendor.module.ts`

The commented code is causing the issue.

`export const gameVendorRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'gamevendors',
    component: InnerPageRegionComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'get',
        component: GameVendorGetComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Get Game Vendor',
          description: 'Get  Game Vendor',
          keywords: ['get', 'game', 'vendor', 'get game vendor'],
          category: 'Game Vendor',
        },
      },
      // {
      //   path: 'create',
      //   component: GameVendorCreateComponent,
      //   data: {
      //     title: 'Create Game Vendor',
      //     description: 'Create  Game Vendor',
      //     keywords: ['create', 'game', 'vendor', 'create game vendor'],
      //     category: 'Game Vendor',
      //     recallAction: actions.ActionTypes.UPDATE_STORE,
      //   },
      // },
     ],
  },
];
export const gameVendorRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(gameVendorRoutes);`

Is there any work around for this issue??